# Discrete math question... Finding largest area

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, optimization

Can anyone help explain to me how to go about solving this question ?:

*Of all the rectangles with perimeter 4, prove that the square has the largest area.*

I know how to solve this algebraically, although how would one go about solving it in context of discrete mathematics

Comment: What do you mean in the context of discrete math? Is usage of the AM-GM inequality not allowed?

Comment: @gnometorule It might not be a discrete math question, but I think that the OP's intention was to get an answer that would use methods and techniques of discrete math. I think this is a valid request. On the other hand, some more context would be welcome.

Comment: Would $x(8-x)=16-16+8x-x^2 =16-(x-4)^2 \leq 16$ be considered a discrete math proof?

Answer (score 4):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Imagine a complete bipartite graph with a total of $2n$ vertices. Let $p + q = 2n$ be the number of vertices on left and right sides of the graph.

This graph has $p\cdot q$ vertices. Imagine a transformation, where you take one vertex from left side and move it to the right side, i.e. $p' = p-1$ and $q' = q+1$. Observe, that this operation removes $q$ edges (we take a vertex from the left) and adds $p-1$ edges (we add vertex to the right). Of course, it is also possible to calculate $(p-1)\cdot(q+1) - p\cdot q = p-q-1$. This tells us, that as long as $p > q+1$ we could transform the graph in to one with more edges.

Finally we arrive, that $p > q+1 \implies |E|<|E'|$ and by symmetry when $q > p+1 \implies |E|>|E'|$. Given that $p+q = 2n$ we conclude that $|E|$ is maximal for $p = q = n$.

I hope it is what you were asking for (put $n = 4$).

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: Why people downvote this? this the only answer here that is discrete math related.

Comment: It was me... I down voted for two reasons: 1) The question has geometry tag too and clearly states rectangle. 2) Even if the OP intended this version, which I highly doubt, the proof, while very nice, proves in this case that: if $1 \leq m,n$ are positive integers and $m+n=8$ then $mn \leq 16$...Way overkill IMO... But I'll remove the downvote...

Comment: Just to emphasize: I highly doubt that what the OP meant was: prove that $1 \cdot 7, 2 \cot 5$ and $3 \cdot 5$ are less than 16. And if he did, I would definitely not prove it this way...

Comment: @N.S. This is funny, because I just wanted to say the same (about $1\cdot 7$, $2 \cdot 6$, etc.). I think I understand your point, but consider this: I tried to imagine how a discrete optimization argument would look like (see e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)) and I arrived at a solution of cutting and pasting discrete rectangles (if anything, the best possible solution would have to have some reference to that, right?). **Cont.**

Comment: **Cont.** The problem was I didn't know how to put it into simple words and the best verbalization I arrived at was using bipartite graphs (not simple enough I guess...). Maybe (probably) it is an overkill, but I really wanted to show (because of the "discrete") the idea of combinatorial optimization. I am not sure if it is appropriate (e.g. to skip rectangles), but it is not only about proving, is it? Anyway, thank you for your attention, should you have any ideas how to improve my answer, please let me know.

Comment: @dtldarek Well, your approach is great for another reason i just realized... You can use it to prove that the problem is true for rational $m,n$ ;)

Comment: But I want to make another point: discrete mathematics doesn't mean that ALL your values have to be integers... For example the Bernoulli inequality is a standard DM problem... And in particular proving that $(1+a)^{2013} \geq 1+2013a$ for all $a >-1$.... In this problem, for example one could argue that $\frac{a_1+...+a_{2^n}}{2^{n}} \geq \sqrt[2^n]{a_1...a_{2^n}}$ is a standard induction problem, and $P(1)$ is just our problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

Let $x,y$ be the sides of the rectangle and the perimeter be $2s$

So, $2(x+y)=2s$

Using algebra,

The area is $xy=x(s-x)=\frac{s^2}4-(x-\frac s2)^2$

As  $(x-\frac s2)^2\ge0,xy\le\frac{s^2}4$

So,the  maximum will be $\frac{s^2}4$ if $x-\frac s2=0\implies x=\frac s2\implies y=s-x=\frac s2=x$

---

Alternatively using calculus, the ares is $A=xy=x(s-x)=sx-x^2$

So, $\frac{dA}{dx}=s-2x$

For the extreme values of $A,\frac{dA}{dx}=0\implies x=\frac s2$

$\frac{d^2A}{dx^2}=-2<0$

So, $x=\frac s2$ will give us the maximum value of the area $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $xy = \frac{1}{4}((x+y)^2-(x-y)^2)$, and since $x+y=2$, we have $xy = 1-\frac{1}{4}(x-y)^2$. Hence $xy \leq 1$, and $x=1, y=1$ results in $xy = 1$. Hence the square has the largest area (and any other lengths have $xy < 1$).